# Ручной подсчет | C#

Tags: c#

Как мне из этого:

```
rez += (int)Math.Pow(p, x.Length - 1 - i) * (int)(x[i]);
```

Вывести формулу, для подсчета на листке.

x - это любое целое число

Вот код:

По нажатию кнопки, я отправляю значение в функцию Reshi(x)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string x = textBox1.Text;

        label6.Text = Convert.ToString(x.Length);
        listBox1.Items.Add(Reshi(x));
}
```

Допустим значение 10. В ListBox я получаю - 1567

Сама функция Reshi(x):

```
public static int Reshi(string x)
    {

        int p = 31;
        int rez = 0; //Результат вычисления 
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {

            rez += (int)Math.Pow(p, x.Length - 1 - i) * (int)(x[i]); 
        }
        return rez;

    }
```

Comment: А что такое `x`?

Comment: @aepot Любое число  целое число, например: 6, 11, 2, 6434 и т.д

Comment: И что именно вам не понятно в формуле?

Comment: @aepot Как определяется i, я что только не подставлял, на бумажке не выходит то, что выходит в C#

Comment: "x - это любое целое число" - У любого целого числа нет свойства `Length`.

Comment: i изменяется от 0 до длины массива x в цикле for. То есть если длина массива 4, то i будет 0 1 2 3. И каждое вычисление суммируется к rez. Длина массива - это сколько чисел в массиве.

Comment: @aepot Не, там x - как string. Т.е я ввожу 2, значит Length = 1, 10 - 2 и т.д. Сейчас попробую просумировать.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, где вы присваиваете x. Либо я ничего не понял, либо у вас ошибка в коде. Напишите, что за задачу ваш код решает.

Comment: @aepot Добавил, что и от куда идет

Comment: Что по-вашему такое `x[i]`?

Comment: @aepot массив, я думаю.

Comment: Нет, `x[i]` - это символ в строке. А преобразование его в int возвращает код этого символа из таблицы символов. Вы же писали этот код? Что должно возвращать `(int)(x[i])`?

Comment: @aepot Код не я писал.  Скорее всего длину массива?

Comment: Мы так с вами ничего не добъемся. Скажите, что вы вычисляете этим кодом, какую задачу он решает или должен решать? Что он должен вычислить? Я не могу вечно здесь пытаться вытягивать из вас информацию, расскажите мне всё сами.

Comment: @aepot Код нужен для решение формулы, по алгоритму Рабина-Карпа. Эта формула была выведена из статьи в википедии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм Рабина-Карпа. Теперь понятнее. Могли же сразу это в вопросе написать?

Чтобы посчитать на бумаге, вам нужно знать код каждого симовла в строке. То есть значение `(int)(x[i])`. Без этого значения вы не посчитаете.

`Math.Pow()` - это возведение степень, а `(int)` перед ним - это отрезание дробной части, что является грубой ошибкой при подобных вычислениях, так как при вычислениях с плавающей точной существует погрешность, и вы можете например получить **5.99999999** (и это нормально), что преобразуется просто в 5. Правильнее формула выглядела бы так.

```csharp
rez += (int)Math.Round(Math.Pow(p, x.Length - 1 - i)) * (int)(x[i]);
```

Тогда можно посчитать. К примеру, пусть `x = "13"`, то есть строка, содержащая число **13**.

По таблице символов, код символа "1" - это 49, код символа "3" соответственно 51.

Длина числа - **2** символа, p = **31**. Считаем

```
алгоритмически так: res = res + (p ^ (x.Length - 1 - i)) * код x[i]

первый символ: (31 ^ (2 - 1 - 0)) * 49 = 1519
второй символ: (31 ^ (2 - 1 - 1)) * 51 = 51
1519 + 51 = 1570
```

Comment: А что за таблица символов?)

Comment: @Snegan как объяснить. Каждому символу соответствует свой числовой код. Вот [пример таблицы](https://unicode-table.com/ru/).

Comment: Ок. Спасибо! @aepot